# Is it possible to build conditional SQL queries with subqueries as result in EA?

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to build a query to give me an object and the connected object. But if there is no connected object I need the same query to return the 1st object nonetheless.

I was trying something like:

```
select (case when EXISTS(query_for_both_objects) then (query_for_both_objects) else (query_for_main_object) end
```

But apparently the result of this condition must return a numeric value...

Does anyone have any hints?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to state which DB you are using with EA!

Answer (score 2):

if you can write the "query both objects" query, you can add the condition to the where clause of the child query, something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... # main query
UNION
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE query_both_objects AND ... # child query
```

similar if it is just a JOIN instead of an UNION